# Delphi - How to make a diagram?

Tags: delphi, diagram

i've been with this problem for some time.. I want to make a diagram, made on runtime with the data that user enters in the other forms etc etc.

My first and actual option, was making cycles and then create the shapes / labels, and applying the shape.top to a variable and increasing it every cycle for like 120. this works great, but if i turn this into a more complex thing, it will give me a lot of work to create the shapes and controlling if they are in top of each other, and more, to connect them with a line.

So, there isn't a component that can help me with this? By the way, is there any component to connect with a simple line 2 objects visually? This would be a nice help too !

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, creating your own diagrams from scratch is a lot of work. I suggest you look to third party components (Google: delphi diagramming) like on page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471/are-there-any-mind-mapping-components-for-delphi-native-vcl-preferably,

Comment: Personally, I'd do it from scratch.

Comment: If you can't find a chart component fitting your demands, IMHO creating a Class, implementing the whole (painting)logic with an assignable canvas would be a better solution than using shapes etc.

Comment: What about TeeChart (http://www.steema.com/teechart/vcl) which is part of newer DelphiVersions?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - yes, we know you'd do that :-)

Comment: DeveloperExpress has an org chart and a flow chart component set. If your time is worth money, then you can probably afford to buy them. They are the closest thing to "Visio as a component set for Delphi" that I have used.

Answer (score 5):

[DelphiArea](http://www.delphiarea.com) has a component called [Simple Graph](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/) that does this type of thing.

I have never used it myself, but I found it today and was impressed with the demo application.